# Finding the minimum point looks easy with a graph but hard with a formula

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, approximation

My research has lead me to the following function:

$$ \frac{\sin(x) [\sin^2(x)\cdot F+ \cos^2(x)/F ]} { 1 - \cos(x) } $$

$F$ is a parameter, and I would like to find the minimum value of this function in the range $x \in [0,\pi/4]$ as a function of $F$.

[The graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pq91qeiyeu) of the function looks pretty simple - when $F\geq 3$ there is a single minimum point which changes smoothly as $F$ changes (the minimum value seems to converge to 4 when $F$ grows).

However, I couldn't find an analytic expression to the minimum point. I tried to find the derivative of the function using [Wolfram Alpha's calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%20%28sin%28x%29%20%28F%20sin%5E2%28x%29%2B%20cos%5E2%28x%29%2FF%20%29%20%2F%20%281%20-%20cos%28x%29%20%29%20%29%2Fdx), but the derivative looks so complicated, I have no idea how to find its zero point.

Is there any trick with which I can find at least an approximate expression to the minimum point as a function of $F$?

Comment: Mutiple top and bottom by $$1+ \cos x$$ will simply the algebra me thinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the numerator of the first derivative i have got after simplification i have got
$$2\,{F}^{2} \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}-3\,{F}^{2}
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}-{F}^{2} \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{4}+3\,{F}^{2}\cos \left( x \right) +3\, \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{3}-{F}^{2}+ \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}-2\,\cos \left( x \right) 
$$
it is a polynomial in $\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying top and bottom leads to the following

$$
(1+\cos x)\sin x\left[F^2 +\cot ^2 x\right]\frac{1}{F}
$$
The derivative with respect to x of the above is
$$
-\sin^2 x \left[F^2 +\cot ^2 x\right]\frac{1}{F} +(\cos x+\cos^2x)\left[F^2 +\cot ^2 x\right]\frac{1}{F} + (1+\cos x)\sin x\left[2\cot x \left(-\mathrm{csc}^2 x\right)\right]\frac{1}{F}
$$
This leads to 
$$
\frac{1}{F\sin^2 x}\left[\left(2\cos^2 x + \cos x -1\right)\left[F^2 +\left(1-F^2\right)\cos^2 x\right]-2(\cos x+\cos^2 x)\right]
$$